# Parsing non consistent json response length in excel vba

Tags: json, excel, vba

Using VBA-JSON v2.0.1 in excel VBA

Here is the JSON response I get from API query

```
{
  "currency": {
    "code": "USD",
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "prefix": "$",
    "postfix": null
  },
  "products": [
    {
      "product_id": xxxxx,
      "model_code": "xxxxx",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": "45.60",
      "total": "45.60",
      "retail_price": "63.84"
    }
  ],
  "shipping": [
    {
      "name": "UPS",
      "price": 43.83,
      "delivery": "3 -10 Days delivery"
    },
    {
      "name": "DHL",
      "price": 20.29,
      "delivery": "2-6 days"
    },
    {
      "name": "FedEx",
      "price": 31.46,
      "delivery": "2-6 days"
    },
    {
      "name": "EMS",
      "price": 25.74,
      "delivery": "7 - 25 Days delivery"
    },
    {
      "name": "Air Mail",
      "price": 11.85,
      "delivery": "10 - 25 Days delivery"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a part of my code to parse the price from "Air Mail" element.

```
result = objHTTP.responseText
Dim Json As Object
Dim resultAirmailprice As String
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(result)
resultAirmailprice = Json("shipping")(5)("price")
Cells(2, 2).Value = resultAirmailprice
```

The code runs fine when the "Air Mail" element is in (5) of "shipping" element. The problem is sometimes there are no "UPS" and "Air Mail" elements, so I got an error.

How to write code to parse the "Air Mail" price and if not exists, parse from "EMS" price(or the cheapest price out of all)?

Comment: I am not familiar with the JsonConverter class, but surely try resultAirmailprice = Json("shipping")("Air Mail")("price"). I say this judged on how the other objects are obtained...

Comment: Does not work. As "Air Mail" is the VALUE of "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Json parser code, it returns a Dictionary Object that contains other Dictionary Objects (sub keys) and, for arrays, Collection Objects. In the Json I see that "shipping" is an array and so the parser returns a Collection Object.

So you can use all the Collection members and methods to manipulate and access it. In particular, you can use `Json("shipping").Count` to check how many elements the Shipping collection has. Or you can iterate over the collection with `For each x in Json("shipping")`.

To check whether you have a Dictionary or a Collection, you could use the `TypeName` function or the `TypeOf..Is` operator.

Comment: Does not work. I got "runtime error, subscript out of range" when there are only 4 subscripts of "shipping".

Comment: shippingmethods = Json("shipping").Count                                                           
        resultAirmailprice = Json("shipping")(shippingmethods)("price")
This works. Thanks.